# Is there a way to add array elements to a formData object, so net core [FromForm] will deserialize them correctly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fetch-api

So, I'm using the feth api to do posts, and it's generally working out really well. But I am having one issue, say I have the following two models:

```cs
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to create a formData object from the html form, which adds the strings and ints just fine. but when I do:

```js
var data = new formData(document.querySelector('form'));

let arr = [{
    Number: "12345678"
},
{
    Number: "87654321"
}
];

data.append('Phones', JSON.stringify(arr)); 
//OR
data.append('Phones', JSON.stringify(arr[0]));
data.append('Phones', JSON.stringify(arr[1]));
//OR
data.append('Phones[]', JSON.stringify(arr[0]));
data.append('Phones[]', JSON.stringify(arr[1]));
//OR
data.append('Phones[0]', JSON.stringify(arr[0]));
data.append('Phones[1]', JSON.stringify(arr[1]));
```

and then post to something like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveContact([FromForm]Contact contact)
{
    ...
}
```

The object is bound as its supposed to, with the correct values for Id, Name, But Phones contains nothing. Does anyone have some input here, its driving me nuts. Thanks!

Comment: Your method takes a Contact object.  Phones is a nested list.  You are not nesting the phones in an object on your formData.

Comment: How would I do that? I am actually using typescript, and I can't append with anything other than a string or Blob, so how to go about that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatever `FromFrom` is, but if using a json string value is valid for the form data, it would be something like `data.append('contact', '{"Phones":[{"Number":123456789}]}')`

Comment: Can't make an edit of less than 6 characters, so, commenting here.  The FormData constructor is capitalized (its not formData, its FormData).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to change your code to the following form:

```
let arr = ["123456","7895555"];

  formData.append('Phones[0].Number', arr[0]);
  formData.append('Phones[1].Number', arr[1]);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: A million thanks to you my friend. I spent hours tying to find an answer to this, so this was great!

Answer (score 2):

Array type property with complex objects

```
const fd = new FormData();

const phones = [
  { number: '123', model: 'model x' },
  { number: '456', model: 'model y' },
];

for (var i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
  fd.append(`phones[][${i}][number]`, phones[i].number);
  fd.append(`phones[][${i}][model]`, phones[i].model);
}
```

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the great solution posted by Yiyi You (very thanks for your post, it helped me a lot) I would recommend also the following solution for my problem that was slightly different.

Javascript code:

```
var formData = new FormData();

let arr = ["123456","7895555"];

formData.append('Phones[0]', arr[0]);
formData.append('Phones[1]', arr[1]);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Contacts/SaveContacts",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },

    error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
        console.log(xhr, resp, text);
    }
});
```

C# code:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ContactsController : Controller
{
    public ContactsController()
    {
    }

    public class PhonesList
    {
        public Dictionary<int, string> Phones{ get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<JsonResult> SaveContacts([FromForm] PhonesList phonesList)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can cycle with the forEach method in an array

```
 arr.forEach((obj,index) => formData.append(`listName[${index}]`,obj.Number))
```

for ES5 >=